# Why orientation of video capture by camera change automatically?

Tags: android, video, camera, surfaceview, android-videoview

I want to open the `camera` and set the preview on the `SurfaceView` in order to record a video.Once done recording,intent to another activity and set the captured video URI in a `VideoView`.But my problem is,the video orientation is change automatically which is different to the camera preview.

This is the Camera preview(I expect the video capture is appear exactly the same):

[image]

But end up the video captured appear like below:

[image]

As you can see,the video is appear in Landscape mode,while the preview is in Portrait mode.

**Here is my code for `surfaceCreated` when open `Camera`**

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    releaseCamera();
    cameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    try{
        mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
    }catch (RuntimeException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    Camera.Parameters parameters;
    parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

    List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    List<Camera.Size> mSupportedVideoSizes = parameters.getSupportedVideoSizes();
    optimalSize = getOptimalVideoSize(mSupportedVideoSizes,
            mSupportedPreviewSizes, videoSurface.getWidth(), videoSurface.getHeight());

    CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    profile.videoFrameWidth = optimalSize.width;
    profile.videoFrameHeight = optimalSize.height;

    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(profile.videoFrameWidth,profile.videoFrameHeight);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        inPreview = true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is how I prepare the video recorder:

```
private boolean prepareRecorder(){

        //# Create a new instance of MediaRecorder
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

        //# Video settings
        mRecorder.setVideoSize(1920,1280);
        mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
        mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

        //# Audio settings
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

        //Max duration 30 seconds
        mRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000);

        //set preview display
        mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());

        //set the ouput of the Mp4 file
        MediaFileHelper mediaFileHelper = new MediaFileHelper();
        outputFile =mediaFileHelper.getOutputVideoFile();
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());

        try{
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }catch (IllegalStateException e){
            Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So my question is:

1) What is the problem causing the Video captured's orientation rotate 180 degree?

2) How can I take the video which orientation is same as the Camera Preview in the surface view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Some devices rotates images and videos after capturing. Use below code to know if the image rotated:

```
public static int getRotation(Context context, Uri imageUri) {
    String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, columns, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) return 0;

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int orientationColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[0]);
    return cursor.getInt(orientationColumnIndex);
}
```

if result is 0 then there is no rotation else you need to rotate it to the original. Use below code:

```
public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bm, int rotation) {
    if (rotation != 0) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotation);
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return bmOut;
    }
    return bm;
}
```

Comment: So I need to put in the `videoUri` into the `getRotation`?

Comment: so the `rotation` in second function is the value return by 1st function??

Comment: The second function I just not understand..Cause now I working on video,video also have Bitmap??

Comment: yes rotation in second function is what returns in first funcion. No, for video there is no bitmap, custom it for video too.

Answer (score 0):

some devices like samsung rotates the image after capture.But through the code we can get the rotation and rotate if it is required.

```
public static int getCameraPhotoOrientation(String imagePath) {
            int rotate = 0;
            try {
                File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                        imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotate = 270;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotate = 180;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        rotate = 90;
                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return rotate;
        }


we can use this method as below


    //Rotate if necessary
int rotate=AppUtil.getCameraPhotoOrientation(imagePath);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(rotate);

// create a file object from path 
File imageFile = new File(path);

//handle Out of memory error
Bitmap bmp=AppUtil.decodeFile(imageFile,100,100);

//Rotate BMP
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: Bro but this is video,not image,is it still the same??